# How can I load a function just once and store the return in a variable?

Tags: php, mysql, class, function, codeigniter

I'm currently going over my user registration code. The part I'm focusing on right now is the password hashing part.

What I do is get a static_salt from a config file, and use mt_rand() to generate a dynamic_salt. What I want to do is have this dynamic_salt stored in my database.

But if I pass the dynamic_salt() method to the create method in order to send it to the salt column of a table in my database it will just run the method again and create a different result from the one produced in my hashed() method.

What would be the best way to achieve what I'm trying to achieve, could you show me an example if possible?

```
public function create() {

                $dbcolumn->password = $this->hashed();
                $dbcolumn->salt = $this->dynamic_salt;
                $this->db->insert('users', $dbcolumn);

    }

public function dynamic_salt() {

            $get_dynamic_salt = mt_rand();
            return $get_dynamic_salt;
}

public function hashed() { //hashing method, that also makes
            // sha1 and salt password
            $static_salt = $this->config->item('encryption_key'); //grab static salt from config file
            $dynamic_salt = $this->dynamic_salt();

        $password = $this->encrypt->sha1($this->input->post('password')); //encrypt user password
            $hashed = sha1($dynamic_salt . $password . $static_salt);

            return $hashed;
}
```

Comment: made the edit  $dbcolumn->salt = $this->dynamic_salt;

Comment: I was told not to use dynamic salt and that it's risky to store a salt in the database

Comment: I guess you mean `$dbcolumn->salt = $this->dynamic_salt();`? also why using all of this? why not just using md5 and set a limitation on the password (alphanumeric, min_length...etc), I know that you can since you are using [CI](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html)!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend that you don't use a dynamic salt, as it will reduce your applications flexibility and is likely not to work in it's current form.

The purpose of a [salt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_%28cryptography%29) is to prevent against [dictionary attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dictionary_attack) that someone could do if they obtained your user database.  In that regard, a static salt is definitely a good idea to implement in your application.

Adding a dynamic salt to each user would mean that you will have to hit a datastore to retrieve the dynamic salt and the hashed version of the user's password, then you will have to perform the CPU intensive hash function (in your code, twice -- you are hashing a hash which is less secure and more likely to have collisions).

Having a simple known, static salt, and a hashed password will allow you to use key/value storage systems like [memcache](http://memcached.org/) should you application grow.  Store the userid as the key and the users hashed password as the value and you will have a lightening fast authentication system.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what the other guy said to me. Is there any point of storing a fake randomly generated salt in the db to confuse the hacker? or is that just a waste of space and time?     public function my_salt() {
                //generate salt
                $my_salt = random_string('alnum', 32);
                return $my_salt;
    }

Comment: It's probably just a waste of time to do anything with a dynamic salt. Even if an attacker managed to get both your static salt and your users passwords, they would still have to go through the process of brute force password cracking to reveal the users original password (or password that produces the same hash).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
public function dynamic_salt() {
    if(!isset($this->dyn_salt))
       $this->dyn_salt = mt_rand();
    return $this->dyn_salt;
}
```

If the `dyn_salt` instance variable doesn't already exist, it will assign it the result of `mt_rand()`, else it will just return the previous value.